# Linker Error - XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, linker

I'm trying to implement push notifications on my iOS build for my Phonegap app. For some reason when executing the build, I'm getting a **Apple Mach-O Linker Error** `Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation`

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I read that I should change my Release Other Linker Flags to `"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a"` but this has already been done and I am still receiving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue because push notifications will not work on simulators. You have to run this on an actual device.